# how to get index.html from other folder

Tags: php

i have 2 folders: "GET" and other is "admin" get contain user access and admin has admin access only. i am trying to place condition in verfy.php file that is if(user=='adminname") then go to admin folder and open up index.html otherwise stay in GET folder and open user file.i dont know whther am i doing wright or wrong because all three comments in if-portion are not working at all:(. here is the portion of my code:

```
<?php
//skiped seesion portion this portion is doing well work after debug 
if($username=="amirlatif")
    {

    //   echo "hello";
            //include('C:\xampp\htdocs\new project\admin');
            ini_set("include_path", "/C:\xampp\htdocs\new project\admin" . ":" .ini_get("include_path"));
    //  dirname('C:\xampp\htdocs\new project\admin\index.html');
    }

   else
   {
             //iss main user profile ka ok!!!

   }
?>
```

Comment: didn't you ask this question a few minutes ago???

Comment: yes. but no body responded to my last question and i almost losing time as i ve to submitt my project.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to set path for specific file in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21363891/how-to-set-path-for-specific-file-in-php)

Comment: that is no reason te re-post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

if($username=="amirlatif") {
    header("location: ../admin/index.php");
} else {
    .....
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to redirect the admin to admin's page, just make a redirection :

```
<?php

if($username=="amirlatif") {
    header("location: path-to-admin-folder/index.php");
} else {
    header("location: path-to-user-folder/index.php");
}

?>
```